# Facing ambiguity in spring constructors, second constructor is getting called

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

I'm facing an issue which is producing an output which is not exactly per the norm. I have read that in case of constructor ambiguity the first constructor gets called. But I'm facing a completely different issue.

My class -

```
public class Addition {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    public Addition() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public Addition(int a, int b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        System.out.println("Constructor : int, int");
    }
    
    public Addition(double a, double b) {
        super();
        this.a = (int)a;
        this.b = (int)b;
        System.out.println("Constructor : double, double");
    }
    
    public void doSum() {
        System.out.println("Sum is -> "+(this.a+this.b));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Addition [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
    }
    
}
```

XML file -

```
<bean class="com.spring.Addition" name="addition1">
    <constructor-arg>
    <value>12</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
    <value>34</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Main code -

```
Addition addition = (Addition)applicationContext.getBean("addition1");
System.out.println(addition);
```

Output-

```
Constructor : double, double
Addition [a=12, b=34]
```

My only concern here is why is the second constructor getting called here, when (int,int) constructor is defined before the (double,double) constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid such ambiguity by specifying the exact data type for constructor, via `type` attribute as follows:

```xml
<bean class="com.spring.Addition" name="addition1">
    <constructor-arg type="int">
        <value>12</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="int">
        <value>34</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sir, isn't ordering of constructors relevant in spring? I have read this at multiple places

Comment: To my knowledge no. I haven't found any reference to that anywhere.

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks